# Beam : Not Event with SideInput into streaming pipeline with DataflowRunner

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I ve tested sideinput into a streaming pipeline with DirectRunner and DataflowRunner with this code :

```java
public class Testsideinput {
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Testsideinput.class);

  static class RefreshCache extends DoFn<Long, String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;
    private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
      c.output("A"+c.element());
      c.output("B"+c.element());
      c.output("C"+c.element());
      c.output("D"+c.element());
      c.output("E"+c.element());
      c.output("F"+c.element());
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    PipelineOptions options = PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).create();
    Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create(options);

    final PCollectionView<List<String>> sideInput2 =
      pipeline.apply("TextIO", TextIO.read().from("<Put your gs://>))
              .apply("viewTags", View.asList());

    final PCollectionView<List<String>> sideInput =
      pipeline.apply("GenerateSequence",
                     GenerateSequence
                        .from(0)
                        .withRate(1, Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
              .apply("Window GenerateSequence",
                     Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(5))))
              .apply("Counts", Combine.globally(Sum.ofLongs()).withoutDefaults())
              .apply("RefreshCache", ParDo.of(new RefreshCache()))
              .apply("viewTags", View.asList());

    final PubsubIO.Read<PubsubMessage> pubsubRead = 
      PubsubIO.readMessages()
              .withIdAttribute("id")
              .withTimestampAttribute("ts")
              .fromTopic("<put your topic>");

    // PCollection<KV<String,Long>> taxi =;
    PCollection<String> taxi = 
      pipeline.apply("Read from", pubsubRead)
              .apply("Window Fixed",
                  Window.into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardSeconds(15))))
                .apply(MapElements.via(new PubSubToTableRow()))
                .apply("key rides by rideid",
                  MapElements
                    .into(TypeDescriptors
                            .kvs(TypeDescriptors.strings(),
                                 TypeDescriptor.of(TableRow.class)))
                    .via(ride -> KV.of(ride.get("ride_id").toString(), ride)))
                .apply("Count Per Element", Count.perKey())
                .apply(
                  ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String,Long>, String>() {

                    @ProcessElement
                    public void processElement(
                      @Element KV<String,Long> value,
                      OutputReceiver<String> out, ProcessContext c) {

                        // In our DoFn, access the side input.
                        List<String> sideinput = c.sideInput(sideInput);
                        List<String> sideinput2 = c.sideInput(sideInput2);

                        LOG.info("sideinput" + sideinput.toString());
                        LOG.info("sideinput2 " + sideinput2.toString());
                        LOG.info("value " + value);
                        out.output("test");
                    }
                  }).withSideInputs(sideInput,sideInput2));
    pipeline.run();
}
```

I have all value of my sideinput (list and map) on DirectRunner but I don't have value with DataflowRunner ( I have no output with `View.CreatePCollectionView/ParDo(StreamingPCollectionViewWriter)` step)

[image]

[image]

do you have an idea to solve this?

Comment: I would move the first "LOG.info" to right after the definition of sideinput, to see if it's hanging on getting the first or second sideinput. Another thing to check is Stackdriver logs: if you're code is stuck there should be a log entry every 5 minutes saying so. Lastly, check that sideInput2's gs:// file is readable by the Dataflow job (try gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt which is world-readable).

Comment: I 've moved LOG and I've tested with different configuration (One or many sideInput, with or without LOG etc ... ) and I have always this bug on DataflowRunner. I use for pubsub one public topic and also for gs (gs://dataflow-samples/shakespeare/kinglear.txt). On Stackdriver logs, I have this log every 5 minutes : "Memory is used/total/max = 1552/2288/4948 MB, GC last/max = 0.76/11.63 %, #pushbacks=0, gc thrashing=false". It seems to be the same issue that : [BEAM-2155](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2155)